# Como criar opção de ver senha digitada em form

Tags: javascript, html

Estou criando uma pagina para se efetuar login e acessar área administrativa de um site. Tudo isso esta sendo feito em `PHP`, porém estou querendo criar uma parada que vi em alguns sites que é a opção de se ver a senha que foi digitada.

Gostaria de saber qual tecnologia é usada para criar esta opção e se possível como cria-la?

Comment: a tecnologia: javascript e html

Comment: Opá, obrigado, tinha encontrado na WEB um forma de fazer, mas estava muito mais complexa, muito obrigado.

PS - Só posso aceitar a resposta em 2 min.

Answer (score 1):

Um código simples pra ocultar e exibir a senha:

```js
function mostrarSenha() {
  var tipo = document.getElementById("senha");
  if(tipo.type == "password"){
      tipo.type = "text";
  }else{
      tipo.type = "password";
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="senha" type="password" value="teste">
<button onclick="mostrarSenha()">Mostrar Senha</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Vê se te ajuda desta forma:

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#showHide").click(function() {
        if ($(".password").attr("type") == "password") {
          $(".password").attr("type", "text");

        } else {
          $(".password").attr("type", "password");
        }
      });
    });
```

```css
#showHide {
      width: 15px;
      height: 15px;
      float: left;
}
#showHideLabel {
      float: left;
      padding-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Password:</td>
        <td>
          <input type="password" name="password" class="password" size="25">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" id="showHide" />
          <label for="showHide" id="showHideLabel">Show Password</label>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Obrigado, também ajuda sim, vou treinar ambas as formas.